# Redirect Users who aren't logged in, aren't post authors and aren't admin. Frontend

Tags: wp-redirect, template-redirect

Very new to PHP and I'm trying to do the following through a snippets plugin but keep getting critical errors:

- Restrict all non-logged in users to home, about and pricing pages. If attempting to access other pages, redirect to "no-permission" message page.
- If user is logged in, allow them to only view posts on the front end if they are the post author. If attempted, redirect to "no-permission" page.
- Admin has full read access on front end.

I've tried with plugins but nothing quite gives me what I want,

Any help is much appreciated, code below:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_non_permitted_users' );

function redirect_non_permitted_users () {
     $userID = get_user_id();
     $authorID = get_the_author_meta(ID);

    if(current_user_can('manage_options')){
 
    }

    elseif( $userID <> $authorID || ! is_user_logged_in() || ! is_front_page() || ! is_page('about') || ! is_page('pricing')){
        wp_redirect('https://www.example.com/no-permission/'); 
    exit;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

`get_user_id()` is not a function so you'll get an error for that.  Additionally, you can get the author id by calling the `$post` global and accessing the property `post_author`

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_non_permitted_users' );

function redirect_non_permitted_users () {
    if (is_admin()) return;
    $userID = get_current_user_id();
    global $post;
    $authorID = absint($post->post_author);
    
    if( $userID !== $authorID && ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_front_page() && ! is_page('about') && ! is_page('pricing')){
        wp_redirect('https://www.example.com/no-permission/');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply although it seems to cause some issues. It redirects to the 'no-permissions' page however it throws a 'too many re-directs/can't load page' error. It also throws the same error when accessing the allowed pages such as 'about'/'home'. Also, to get admin access across all pages on the front-end I had to revert to back to the the if/else statement to do nothing if it's the site admin.

Comment: Updated.  I forgot `post_author` is a string.  Added an admin page check, but template redirect shouldn't be called in the admin.

Comment: Thanks Howard - that certainly fixed some things for the admin. Still issues if it's not the admin. I think I know the issue though, just not too sure how to write the syntax. With "$userID !== $authorID" - would that not cause a loop because the redirect destination was created by the admin?

Comment: is_admin doesn't mean "is administrator" it means, "in the admin section"  - I think your condition is unclear.  Clarify the rules for redirection please (in your question.)

Comment: I've updated the condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot Howard it's been a big help and sorry if the question was vague. I ended up getting what I needed with the code I've posted above.

Answer (score 0):

This is seems to do what I want. Issue was $userID conflicting with $authorID on the 'no-permission' page causing a redirect loop.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_non_permitted_users' );

function redirect_non_permitted_users () {
  if (is_admin()) return;
  $userID = get_current_user_id();
  global $post;
  $authorID = absint($post->post_author);

  if (is_page('no-permission') || current_user_can('manage_options')){
  return;
  }  

  if( ($userID !== $authorID || ! is_user_logged_in()) && ! 
  is_front_page() && ! is_page('about') && ! is_page('pricing')){
    wp_redirect('https://www.example.com/no-permission/');
    exit;
  }
}
```